# Combine two Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to combine two `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
I'm new to Excel VBA code, how can I do this? Code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        rv = r.Value
        'Peak Flow Doctor Warning and Weight Gain Warning
        If rv = 180 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If
        If rv = 120 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
        End If
        If rv >= 450 Then
            MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        'Weight Gain Warning
        rv = r.Value
        If rv = 90 Then
            MsgBox "''LIKELY TO EXACERBATE COPD SYMPTOMS''" & vbCrLf & "''CHRONIC ASTHMA OR EMPHYSEMA PROBABLE''", vbCritical, "WARNING"
        End If
        If rv = 95 Then
            MsgBox "''IF SWELLING IN ANKLES PROBABLE FLUID RETENTION''" & vbCrLf & "''POSSIBILITY OF HEART FAILURE IF UNATTENDED''", vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING"
        End If
      Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you mean combine? Do you want it to do both procedures on a single change event? Do you need them done in a specific order? Try to explain your exact problem, and what you have tried, then we can maybe provide a solution.

Comment: an easy way is to re-name the variables from the second private sub. An example, rng -> rng2 : r -> r2.

Comment: There are two different Target Ranges both returning Msgbox pendant on range values, but you cant run two Private Sub. I've tried Maki example, rng -> rng2 : r -> r2, but just get a Compile error at Next r. As I'm new to VBA i'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a merge of your current 2 `Worksheet_Change` events.

You can also use `Select Case` to clean-up your code a little.

***Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81"))
        For Each r In rng
            'Peak Flow Doctor Warning and Weight Gain Warning
            Select Case r.Value
                Case 180
                    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"    
                Case 120
                    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
                Case Is >= 450
                    MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
            End Select
        Next r
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C93:AD93"))
        For Each r In rng
            'Weight Gain Warning
            Select Case r.Value
                Case 90
                    MsgBox "''LIKELY TO EXACERBATE COPD SYMPTOMS''" & vbCrLf & "''CHRONIC ASTHMA OR EMPHYSEMA PROBABLE''", vbCritical, "WARNING"
                Case 95
                    MsgBox "''IF SWELLING IN ANKLES PROBABLE FLUID RETENTION''" & vbCrLf & "''POSSIBILITY OF HEART FAILURE IF UNATTENDED''", vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING"
            End Select
        Next r
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai your an absolute genius, It work very well, thank you so much for your help really appreciated.